# DOMPDF text is bolder than normal

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf

I cant understand why the font color in DOMPDF is bolder than normal.

[jsfiddle with the html](http://jsfiddle.net/cuZvL/)

Image comparing HTML to DOMPDF:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's an [unresolved bug](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=476) where the presence of an image can cause text to render in this way. I have found that deleting the image in Acrobat Pro seems to fix the text. What PDF reader (including version) are you using?

Comment: Whoever down-voted, can you provide a reason/edit so that the question can be improved to make it more useful to the community. It is a valid issue.

Comment: I am using Adobe Reader X v10.1.3, but the DOMPDF outputs the PDF using Acrobat 4.x

Comment: You are correct, dompdf produces documents based on the PDF 1.3 spec. I don't think there's anything specific about the spec that's the problem. Star the linked bug from my earlier comment so you know when the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Starred it. I also got problem with borders, their size is double... any idea why?

Comment: Did you post somewhere else about this ... sounds familiar?

Comment: FYI, the image problem appear to occur with 8bit images. I tried a 32-bit PNG version of the logo, and a JPG, and neither caused the same problem in the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BrianS said, the cause for the problem is PNG 8 bit.

I made a function which converts all PNGs to JPGs and that solved the problem.
This is good if you don't which format it is > PNG or JPG.

Thanks BrianS.