# PHP-inserted text is pixelated/blur when PDF is generated with DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

My issue is that text inserted with `$pdf->page_text();` inside the HTML structure of the document (between `<body></body>` tags) renders weirdly when opening the PDF. It is pixelated, leaking and kind of blurry. HTML text renders just fine though.

**Code that generates the PDF**

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('fiche.pdf');
```

**Code that inserts text in the HTML document**

```
<script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("Arial");
        $yP = $pdf->get_height() - 30;
        $yD = $pdf->get_height() - 18;
        $xP = $pdf->get_width() / 2 - Font_Metrics::get_text_width("Page 10 sur 10", $font, $size) / 2;
        $xD = $pdf->get_width() / 2 - Font_Metrics::get_text_width("xx/xx/xxxx", $font, $size) / 2;
        $pdf->page_text($xP, $yP, "Page {PAGE_NUM} sur {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 12, array(0,0,0));
        $pdf->page_text($xD, $yD, date('d/m/y'), $font, 12, array(0,0,0));
    }
</script>
```

**Environment**

- PHP5.4
- FreeBSD 9
- DOMPDF 0.6.0
- PDF Viewer 0.1.8

**Actual rendering**

[image: blurry-text]

I have seen this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652821/dompdf-text-is-bolder-than-normal) and [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/482). My problem has nothing to do with images because I tried converting them to JPG and also deleting them from the document and text still renders blurry.

I kindly request your assistance here. Ask me if more info is needed.

Many thanks.

Comment: I tried what you posted and it rendered fine. It might help to see the output produced by your system.

Comment: It could be a viewer issue. Arial is a built-in font, not one supplied by dompdf. What happens if you use one of the Deja Vu fonts (e.g. Deja Vu Sans).